# Why did they bring back paper ballots in the 2021 Andhra Pradesh local elections?

Tags: india

In this [video](https://youtu.be/JCWR19PFQoA?t=173), CBI Ex JD Laxmi Narayana says they brought back paper ballots in the 2021 Andhra Pradesh local elections. This is a translation of his words:

> He saying they introduced **ballot box again**, till now we used EVM voting
> machines

Why did they bring back paper ballots in the [2021 Andhra Pradesh local elections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_Andhra_Pradesh_local_elections)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem that this is a response to "glitches" in the 2019 LS elections (see [a report in the India times](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/elections/lok-sabha/india/evm-glitches-in-many-places-as-voting-for-ls-assembly-polls-begins-in-andhra/articleshow/68825425.cms?from=mdr))

The advantage of paper voting is that it is very simple and transparent for the voter, and automatically creates a "paper trail".  There can be no conspiracy theories about criminals "hacking" a piece of paper.

The disadvantages are that paper voting makes ballot stuffing easy and counting hard.